# How to encrypt a section within web.config using aspnet_regiis -pe or -pef

Tags: configuration, encryption, web.config

I am a developer trying to encrypt part of my web.config file in an ASP.NET site (first time I've tried this...).

Having repeated failures with all types of syntax changes, so perhaps better to post here. Here is one example of a failure (I copied web.config into c:\temp) from cmd prompt hung off Visual Studio 2010 program tree:

Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.

**C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>aspnet_regiis -pef "applicationSettings/Webclient.Properties.Settings" "c:\temp"
Encrypting configuration section...
The configuration section 'applicationSettings/Webclient.Properties.Settings' was not found.
Failed!**

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>

- Originally, I posed the question in SO here (no real help after 3 days):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481562/aspnet-regiis-pe-cannot-find-my-configuration-section-in-net-v4-0-30319

- Then I posted question here for help:

[http://forums.asp.net/t/1748951.aspx/1?How+to+get+ASPNET_REGIIS+to+encrypt+a+section+of+my+web+config+file](http://forums.asp.net/t/1748951.aspx/1?How%20to%20get%20ASPNET_REGIIS%20to%20encrypt%20a%20section%20of%20my%20web%20config%20file)

- Latest forum where I've sought help:

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/partnerdevaspnet/thread/faac591f-498e-461d-970f-c2d8f9a7a4f5/

- Here is the **web.config**:

  `<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
  <configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" 
          type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System,    Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="WebClient.Properties.Settings" 
          type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
          requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="FileServiceProxy.Properties.Settings" 
          type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
          requirePermission="false"/>
  </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <applicationSettings>
    <WebClient.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="GROUPERpassword" serializeAs="String">
            <value>12345abcde</value>
        </setting>
        <setting name="MARLINpassword" serializeAs="String">
            <value>abcdef12345</value>
        </setting>
    </WebClient.Properties.Settings>
    <FileServiceProxy.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="FileServiceProxy_ASMXproxy_FileService" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://MDWDATA/sdkTrimFileServiceASMX/FileService.asmx</value>
        </setting>
    </FileServiceProxy.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
  <trace enabled="false" pageOutput="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
  <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
  </compilation>
  <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm"/>
  <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="65536" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
  <defaultDocument>
    <files>
      <remove value="default.aspx" />
      <remove value="index.cfm" />
      <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
      <remove value="index.html" />
      <remove value="index.htm" />
      <remove value="Default.asp" />
      <remove value="Default.htm" />
      <remove value="FileService.asmx" />
      <add value="ColdFusionFormPOSTtoGROUPER.htm" />
    </files>
  </defaultDocument>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="67108864" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
  <tracing>
    <traceFailedRequests>
      <add path="*">
        <traceAreas>
          <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
          <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
          <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
          <add provider="WWW Server"  areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI" verbosity="Verbose" />
        </traceAreas>
        <failureDefinitions statusCodes="401.3,500" />
      </add>
    </traceFailedRequests>
  </tracing>
  </system.webServer>
  </configuration>`

Comment: Formatting issue: I have tried everything I know about how to show the XML of the web.config file but all I get is the little mal-formed snippet. Proper look at web.config content is at other links above if you care to help.

Comment: I read for a minute and was really having a hard time putting the different threads together - I think it'd be a great help to those trying to answer if you could possibly summarize some of the outside resources here?